# In scala project to create power point and got import error. import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel. Tried import ss works

Tags: scala, apache-poi, powerpoint

Can apache poi support power point generation using scala language.

I tried adding version 3.15-beta and 3.17 none of them works

Anything from import org.apache.poi.xslf._ and import org.apache.poi.sl._ cannot be resolved. But the one form import org.apache.poi.ss._ is working which is only for excel sheet. I need jar to create power point.

the sbt file as below:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.poi" % "poi" % "4.0+",
    "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml" % "4.0+",
    "org.apache.poi" % "poi-ooxml-schemas" % "4.0+",
    "org.apache.poi" % "ooxml-schemas" % "1.3",
    "org.apache.xmlbeans" % "xmlbeans" % "2.6.0",
    "org.apache.commons" % "commons-collections4" % "4.0"
)
```

the code in project as below:

```
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFPictureShape
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFShape
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlide
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlideLayout
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFSlideMaster
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTable
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTableCell
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTableRow
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTextParagraph
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTextRun
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XSLFTextShape



  object PPTProcessHelper {

    def getTemplateTblStyle(
      ntable:          XSLFTable,
      textColList:     ArrayList[Integer],
      emptyRowList:    List[Integer],
      templateCellMap: Map[Integer, TemplateCell],
      tblCol:          Int,
      tblRow:          Int): Double = {
      var tblCell: XSLFTableCell = null
      var hasText: Boolean = false
      var maxHeight: Double = 0d
      var templateCell: TemplateCell = new TemplateCell()
      var rowHeight: Double = 0d
      var tableRowCount: Int = 0
}
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve]. If you edit your question according to those guidelines, others can help you better.

Comment: 1 - make sure you include all the right jars, see http://poi.apache.org/components/index.html#components . 2 - use a recent supported version!

Comment: @jrook I edit my questions and post the code. However this just simple import jar problem. the issue is I cannot any import from import org.apache.poi.sl and import org.apache.poi.xslf cannot be resolved

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks for your response. I tried different version 3.17,  4.0+ and 4.1+, none of them works. the only thing I didn't change is scala version is 2.11.11 since this is required by the whole project

Comment: Look at the components page I've already linked you to - you're probably missing some of the Apache POI jars or their dependencies

Comment: @Gagravarr Thanks, I resolved it already. It's my mistake. After rebuild though sbt, the project didn't refresh automatically. After I did it manually, everything works now